# Resolving an Xpath query

Tags: xml, xpath

Hi I have a doubt related to XPath.

My xml file looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<name xmlns="http://localhost/book" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/book books.xsd">
Java and XML
</name>
```

here is the xpath query and its result

`/*` - returns element "name"

`/*/text()` - returns text "Java and XML"

`/name` - no result

`/name/text()` - no result

Why specifying name is not giving any result?

Comment: It is possible because that the `name` node missed the namespace. How do you use the XPath query, in XSL file or application? Can you provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

That is because element `name` is declared in `http://localhost/book`. Therefore in XPath query you should specify it. As a rule you should pass to your XML engine namespace and it prefix, then query your XML using full-qualified name, i.e.:

```
/ns:name/text()
```

However you can use other technique specifying namespace in query, i.e.:

```
/*[local-name() = 'name' and namespace-uri() = 'http://localhost/book']
```

Comment: /ns:name/text() - this is reporting that it can't resolve ns.I changed xmlns="http://localhost/book" to xmlns:ns="http://localhost/book" in my xml file

Comment: @GaneshP, That is because you should pass this info in your XML engine, in other words your XML engine needs to know how to correlate namespace with prefix.

Comment: Thanks Kirill. I'm actually using Editix xml editor. So there should be some way specifying it in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

**Read about the NamespaceManager and how to use it in EditX here**: http://www.japisoft.com/doc-editix/manual/index.html#mozTocId544189